# Purpose of MANIFEST file on WAR files

Tags: java, war, manifest, manifest.mf

In a very general way I understand what's the purpose of the MANIFEST file in JAR files, it's to specify the MainClass and other metadata that I'm not aware of.

I'd like to know if there's a more general definition of the purpose of this file, for example, **in a *WAR* file what would be the use of it**?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of info? I mean, for JAR files I think I know, but WAR files?

Comment: I've read people something about specify dependencies there, is that correct?

Comment: Cfr. [What is use of MANIFEST.MF in WAR/JAR/EAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11139643/452614). Not specifically about WAR but it gives an idea.